# Is Entity Framework supposed to be closing/re-opening connections per-query?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 with Code First, and seeing SQL Profiler logs that have Logins/Logouts before and after every query. Shouldn't EF be keeping the connection open to the server, and re-using it, instead of closing and re-opening it per-query? I am using Ninject to have my EF context live per HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

According to this blog post, it looks like this may be okay, just misleading, and if you show the "EventSubClass" column in SQL Profiler, you can see it's not really opening new connections, they're pooled.

http://blog.dotsmart.net/2011/03/17/is-sql-server-profiler-showing-connection-pooling-not-working/

Comment: The connection is pooled as long as certain conditions are met, the biggest being that the connection string is identical to a connection in the pool. But yes, as long as it's able to use a connection from the pool the most expensive part of the operation is avoided.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Entity Framework manages the connection to the database. However, you can manually manage both connections and transactions in your Entity Framework application.

You can explicitly open through:

dbContext.Connection.Open();

In terms of connection pool, the default connection pool size is 100.
the "Max Pool Size" property of a connection string can help you here.